# Term for an 'overall' convex function

Tags: polynomials, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Mathworld defines a [convex function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexFunction.html) as

> (...) a continuous function whose value at the midpoint of every interval in its domain does not exceed the arithmetic mean of its values at the ends of the interval.

Is there any name for a function for which the above is true, but only for intervals larger than sone value. Maybe something like that:

> A *< insert-function-name-here >* is a continuous function $f$ for which there exists such a (finite) value of $p\in\mathbb{R^+}$ such that the value at the midpoint of every interval larger than $p$ in the domain of $f$ does not exceed the arithmetic mean of its values at the ends of the interval.

Specifically I'm thinking about functions such as
$$f(x) = x/20 - x^2/80 + x^4/20000$$
in the context of optimisation. Basically functions which go to infinity towards the edges of their domain and have a general 'dip' in the middle. The above function is not convex, but it can be optimised and its (global) minimum can be easily found. $-f(x)$ is also not convex and it cannot be optimised.

Maybe something like 'wide-sense convex'? I'd prefer to use an established term rather than come up with my own though.

Comment: The characterization by midpoints is only valid for continuous functions. I.e. if $f$ is midpoint-convex and continuous then it is convex.

Comment: Also what would be the use of this 'wide sense convexity'? Is it useful to prove something?

Comment: @daw As I've eluded to in the question; I'm asking in the context of optimisation. Such a function would be *'optimisable'*, possibly with some local minima, regardless of the choice of the starting point. This is in contrast to, e.g. $f(x) = -x^2$ - no minima, or $f(x) = (x^3)/3000 + (x^2)/200$ - a minimum, but also falls off to $-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: I think you are overstating the value of the particular structure in your example function. Optimizing any 1-D function bounded below really isn't going to be that hard. The challenge is to identify a principle of functions _that readily scales to the multidimensional case_. And a function with a couple of dips like this in 1-D, frankly, scales out to a function with lots of local minima in multiple dimensions. It's not going to be "easy" to optimize.

Comment: I guess I can sign on to the idea that a function that satisfies $f(x)\rightarrow+\infty$ whenever $\|x\|\rightarrow+\infty$ has some advantages in optimization practice. But I think primarily what that buys you is the opportunity to bound your search space. And you often get that in optimization _anyway_, naturally.